# Passing multi-Array from Model to a Controller

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a controller with an array $added_tabs. I pass this array to a function model.
In my model if i print the results everything works fine, but if i return $row to my controller again, only show 1 record.

Any ideas?

In my controller i have this:

```
$this->load->model('check_info/check_post_day');
$admin_post_day = $this->check_post_day->check_post($added_tabs);
echo "<pre>"; print_r($admin_post_day); echo "</pre>";
```

In my model i have this:

```
class Check_post_day extends CI_Model {

function check_post($data) { 
    foreach ($data as $info) {
        $row = array(); 
            $query = $this->db->query("
            SELECT

            admin_post_day.page_id,
            admin_post_day.admin_id,
            admin_post_day.hour_post,
            admin_post_day.discount,
            admin_post_day.url,
            admin_post_day.message_post,
            admin_post_day.voucher,
            admin_post_day.date_saved,

            fb_pages.page_id,
            fb_pages.id_fb_pages,

            fb_pages_admin.access_token

            FROM admin_post_day

            inner join fb_pages
            on admin_post_day.page_id=fb_pages.page_id

            inner join fb_pages_admin
            on fb_pages.id_fb_pages=fb_pages_admin.id_fb_pages

            where admin_post_day.page_id LIKE " . $info['page_id'] . "
            ORDER BY admin_post_day.date_saved DESC LIMIT 1
            ");
    foreach ($query->result_array() as $row) {
    $info = $row;
    }
        if ( !empty( $query ) ) {
            return $row;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
}
```

//upate

```
class Check_post_day extends CI_Model {

function check_post($data) { 
    foreach ($data as $info) {
        $row = array(); 
            $query = $this->db->query("
            SELECT

            admin_post_day.page_id,
            admin_post_day.admin_id,
            admin_post_day.hour_post,
            admin_post_day.discount,
            admin_post_day.url,
            admin_post_day.message_post,
            admin_post_day.voucher,
            admin_post_day.date_saved,

            fb_pages.page_id,
            fb_pages.id_fb_pages,

            fb_pages_admin.access_token

            FROM admin_post_day

            inner join fb_pages
            on admin_post_day.page_id=fb_pages.page_id

            inner join fb_pages_admin
            on fb_pages.id_fb_pages=fb_pages_admin.id_fb_pages

            where admin_post_day.page_id LIKE " . $info['page_id'] . "
            ORDER BY admin_post_day.date_saved DESC LIMIT 1
            ");

    if($query->num_rows() > 0){
        $rows[] = $query->result_array();
    }
}
return $rows;
}
 }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course , you use `return` in the loop , so right after the first run - it returns the output.

Change:

```
if ( !empty( $query ) ) {
    return $row;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

To:

```
if ( !empty( $query ) ) {
    $rows[] = $row;
}
```

And after the loop ends:

```
if ( count($rows) > 0 ) {
    return $rows;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

**UPDATE**
Please notice that you're wasting resources by using that second loop.
It's a bad practice in my opinion.

```
   foreach ($query->result_array() as $row) {
    $info = $row;
    }
```

Consider adding the output of the `result_array` function and handle it instead.

And according to @RocketHazmat 's comment,

> empty($query) doesn't do what you think it does.

You should change the condition to:

```
if( count($row) > 0)
```

**UPDATE 2**
Instead of the second loop and condition:

```
if($query->num_rows() > 0){
    $rows[] = $query->result_array();
}
```

please notice that if `result_array` returns an array $rows would be a multi-dimensional array.

Comment: Ok, how can i send all the arrays???? cause i have tried to use the return outside the loop and doesnt work anyway

Comment: Patient my friend , pressed enter too soon :) Update me if it works now.

Comment: `empty( $query )` doesn't do what you think it does.  `$query` is an object returned by CodeIgniter, it is *not* your result set.  It will *never* be empty.

Comment: The OP used it so I believed he's familiar with what `empty` is all about.

Comment: @OfirBaruch: The OP used it incorrectly.  From the docs (http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/queries.html): `The query() function returns a database result object`.

Comment: @OfirBaruch Yes, i will. Just need to wait more 5 minutes before i accept it.

Comment: I don't understand- he said "In my model if i print the results everything works fine", meaning print_r($admin_post_day); did indeed print all the items in the result array. If check_post() only returns one row, how is it possible that print_r($admin_post_day); returned the entire array?

Comment: @techjunkie.css when i said that the print returns all, was returning in the model function. In the main controller where i have the var $admin_post_day only showed one record.

Comment: @RocketHazmat Ok, can you explain me how can i check if the query is empty?

Comment: @subrui: You can check how many rows the query returned using `$query->num_rows()`.

Comment: @RocketHazmat - Updated my answer according to your comment.

Comment: Need to change this part?

foreach ($query->result_array() as $row) {
     $data[] = $row;
    }
   
   if ( !empty( $query ) ) {
    $rows[] = $row;
   }
  }
  
 if ( count($rows) > 0 ) {
 return $rows;
 } else {
 return false;
 }